# Possible ID conflicts with multiple JVMs and Eclipselink Table sequencing?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, apache-tomee

I've been researching a change from auto-increment IDs in MySQL with JPA and Eclipselink to the table generation strategy. I plan to use the default allocationSize of 50.

Will I run into concurrency issues with multiple JVMs hitting the same tables? The worst case example can be several developers with TomEE instances running on their desktops hitting the same development DB. It could also occur in production if we decide to scale TomEE horizontally.

In this case, will there ever be a collision of IDs if multiple JVMs startup simultaneously and may be inserting data into the same table concurrently? It isn't clear from looking at various documentation sites.

The best description I've found of the process is: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Relational_Projects_(ELUG)#Table_Sequencing

Comment: Well, unless MySQL doesn't provide a reliable autoincrement/serial column, it shouldn't be an issue. Each JVM will get their separate chunk, so they don't overwrite each other's ids.

Comment: The proposed change is to move away from autoincrement IDs.

Comment: table sequencing selects the next values and updates the rows in its own transaction, so multiple processes will not get the same batch of values.  Turn on SQL logging to see what occurs on the first insert after startup.  Each process must check the values and lock them before they can use any.

Comment: OK, thanks Chris. Post as an answer and I'll accept it.